# Relation between correlation and linear regression

Tags: r, regression, correlation

I have a doubt about use of linear regression.

1. If the correlation between two variables is 0, is there any use of applying linear regression on those variables?
2. If possible can you explain when we should use regression methods (only when correlation is +-1?).

Comment: If you have two variables x and y and you want to express y = f(x), where f is some transformation and the Pearson correlation coefficient for x and y is zero, then you can't apply linear regression as the transformation f, because it won't be able to produce informative prediction. It doesn't mean there is no weird nonlinear dependency. In linear regression the higher is the absolute value of the Pearson correlation coefficient between two variables, the better it works.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of your questions make sense. One does not decide whether to use linear regression on the basis of a correlation coefficient. To learn about the use of linear regression and when linear regression is appropriate, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) or any introductory statistics textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation (Pearson) is defined as `rho=CovXY/(Sx.Sy)` and the linear regression coefficient is `beta=CovXY/(Sx^2)`, where `Sx` and `Sy` are standard deviations.

If `rho=0` and there is variation in the data, it must be `CovXY=0`. Then `beta=0`.

But there are situations even when `rho<>0` the linear regression does not make cense ([spurious regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship)).